# mariadb: performance parallel queries

Tags: mysql, mariadb

we need your help to understand more about the internals from mariadb 10.2..

We have one complex query. If we run this query alone, it needs 5 seconds. But if we run the same query parallel, each query runs factors longer.

The query includes a random integer in the where part, so we don't use query caching. Our server has available 4 cpus.

Our observations:

(1) run 1 query => ~5 seconds

(2) run the same query 4 times (parallel) => each query runs ~5.5 seconds

(3) run the same query 7 times (parallel) => each query runs ~7 seconds

(4) run the same query 10 times (parallel) => each query runs ~11 seconds

We optimized the query, that we not need a temporary disk table. We can see, that all 4 cpus has a load roundabout 80-90%.

But we have no ideas, why the execution time is so different.

Thanks, Rene

Comment: Whats your disk i/o like during the queries? Any wait time?

Comment: Here is me top resultat.
%Cpu0  : 74.3 us,  4.3 sy,  0.0 ni, 21.3 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st

%Cpu1  : 75.8 us,  3.6 sy,  0.0 ni, 20.5 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st

%Cpu2  : 75.0 us,  3.7 sy,  0.0 ni, 21.3 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st

%Cpu3  : 73.9 us,  4.3 sy,  0.0 ni, 21.7 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st

KiB Mem : 16268764 total,   661676 free,   936976 used, 14670112 buff/cache

KiB Swap:  6713340 total,  6588140 free,   125200 used. 14335736 avail Mem

There are no IO waits.

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever had your laptop slow down because you have too many applications open?

Any computer has a finite amount of resources. CPU, RAM, disk. If you run a process that is using a lot of resources, there's less available for the next process.

It's the same with parallel threads, each running a query. They each need to use some CPU to process data. If the data is on disk, it needs to be loaded into the buffer pool, and this uses some disk bandwidth.

Furthermore, some internal data structures require global locks. Like if two threads are trying to load pages into the buffer pool, there's a global lock that both threads need so they can find a free page. One thread grabs that lock, does its work, and releases the lock. The second thread has been waiting in the meantime. This happens many times a second, but the more threads, the more contention there is.

Comment: Thanks. How can I show this locks? Is there any tooling? 
There are variables where I can change the behavior? For example change size of buffer cache?

Comment: Yes there are lots of tools and configuration options. I suggest you read [High Performance MySQL](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920022343.do).

Answer (score 0):

Let's try to speed up the query.

It sounds like the query is doing a table scan or some other I/O-intensive task.  Note that disks (in most systems) are single-threaded.  That is, your "in parallel" does not extend to the I/O.

"We optimized the query, that we not need a temporary disk table." -- That's just one of many optimizations.  Let's look more more.

Do you have any "composite" indexes?

Do you hide indexed columns inside function calls?

Show us the query, together with `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`